sort all arrays in a JSON file depth-first to get a consistent order
I'm tracking the configuration of some system in JSON format in a revision control system.
Unfortunately that configuration is retrieved using some closed-source proprietary command, and the output changes from one run to the next as the order in objects and arrays is more or less random.
One time, it will output:
{
  "fru": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "attr": [
         {"name": "colour", "value": "blue"},
         {"name": "length", "value": 12}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "attr": [
         {"name": "colour", "value": "red"},
         {"name": "length", "value": 1}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "tags": ["x", "y"]
}

And the next time:
{
  "tags": ["y", "x"],
  "fru": [
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "attr": [
         {"name": "length", "value": 1},
         {"name": "colour", "value": "red"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "attr": [
         {"name": "colour", "value": "blue"},
         {"name": "length", "value": 12}
      ]
    }
  ]
}

That means that from the PoV of git diff, everything changes from one run to the next even though it's exactly the same system.
In all the arrays, the order is not relevant. The order doesn't matter in the attributes of the objects either. So if I could post-process that output so that the objects and arrays have their attributes and members in a consistent order, I would guarantee the output doesn't change when the system doesn't change and the changes as seen by git diff would be more likely to reflect the changes in the system.
jq -S gets me a lot of the way by:

sorting attributes inside objects
putting separate object attributes and array members on separate lines (git diff is line-based).

For the example above, that gives me:
{
  "fru": [
    {
      "attr": [
        {
          "name": "colour",
          "value": "blue"
        },
        {
          "name": "length",
          "value": 12
        }
      ],
      "name": "foo"
    },
    {
      "attr": [
        {
          "name": "colour",
          "value": "red"
        },
        {
          "name": "length",
          "value": 1
        }
      ],
      "name": "bar"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    "x",
    "y"
  ]
}

And:
{
  "fru": [
    {
      "attr": [
        {
          "name": "length",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "colour",
          "value": "red"
        }
      ],
      "name": "bar"
    },
    {
      "attr": [
        {
          "name": "colour",
          "value": "blue"
        },
        {
          "name": "length",
          "value": 12
        }
      ],
      "name": "foo"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    "y",
    "x"
  ]
}

That's better, but not there yet, as arrays are not sorted  (understandably).
Note that the real life file is more complex with arrays containing other arrays of objects containing more arrays...
My thinking to address that is to sort all arrays, starting with the deepest ones based on the JSON string representation of the values, for instance .fru[0].attr sorted with {"name": "colour", "value": "blue"} before {"name": "length", "value": 12} because the {"name":"colour","value":"blue"} string sorts before the length one, and then the .fru array sorted with foo before bar because {"attr":[..."blue"... (with the attr attribute moved before name in alphabetic order) sorts before {"attr":[..."red"....
I can get the paths of all arrays, depth first with:
$ jq -c '[paths(arrays)]|reverse' a
[["tags"],["fru",1,"attr"],["fru",0,"attr"],["fru"]]

I can sort an array based on the JSON string representation of their members with:
jq '.array|=sort_by(tojson)'

But how could I combine the two to apply the second to all the arrays returned by the first?
Or is there a better way to post-process that JSON so the order remains consistent?
If jq is not the best tool for that, I'm happy to consider perl's JSON modules or the ruby/python equivalents.

I never understood why people use arrays containing structs with one entry "name" and one entry "value" instead of just a dictionary, like { "colour": "red", "length": 12 }

@gnasher729 Arrays are ordered, structs are not. That's one reason. It also allows for duplicate names, and names that are not strings. { "name": { "en": "table", "eo": "tablo" }, "value": 12 }

The walk() function seems perfect for this use case. It recursively applies the given filter to every JSON element, bottom up, and returns the result. As a matter of fact, sorting all arrays is one of the examples in the documentation:
$ jq -S 'walk(if type == "array" then sort else . end)' a
{
  "fru": [
    {
      "attr": [
        {
          "name": "colour",
          "value": "blue"
        },
        {
          "name": "length",
          "value": 12
        }
      ],
      "name": "foo"
    },
    {
      "attr": [
        {
          "name": "colour",
          "value": "red"
        },
        {
          "name": "length",
          "value": 1
        }
      ],
      "name": "bar"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    "x",
    "y"
  ]
}

If all you need is any consistent sort order, that should do the trick (since jq's sort filter does define a deterministic ordering of all elements, including objects), but if you specifically want to sort array elements by their string representations, you can of course replace sort with your sort_by(tojson).
Incidentally, you might find it useful to pair this with a JSON diff tool that can compare two JSON documents structurally (e.g. ignoring key order in objects), rather than doing a text-based comparison, but that's another matter.

Thanks. Perfect indeed. Default sort order is better than the one I envisioned as at least arrays of numbers are sorted numerically. Thanks for the hint to json diff tools as well though the one I've tried so far was not as useful as not giving context and took several minutes to run one diff on my file (I guess they also wouldn't help for git blame).

There's also gron, which makes json greppable. It sorts it by default. Therefore, diff <(gron a) <(gron b) makes for a very readable output, since you not only see the differences, but also where in the json hierarchy the difference is. It might not be as performant as native jq tho.

The issue in the question is that the order of arrays etc. is "more or less random". Transforming the JSON with gron therefore wouldn't solve the problem. You would just get the same data in a different format, but still in random order.

I see, gron's sorting only applies to the keys of an object/struct, it keeps the array order. My bad!

Yes, gron behaves like jq -S in that instance. Still, thanks for making me aware of that tool, it looks like a very handy one, even if not for that specific case.
